# How to mix PHP and Rails deployment?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have a CentOS VPS and deployed a few PHP apps already, i.e.:

```
/var/www/html (some static pages)
/var/www/html/blog (wordpress blog)
```

Now I'd like to add an Rails app, how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way: would be to shift your static (non-php) pages inside the rails application. (That is the public folder inside your rails app). Then configure your server/domain name to have your rails app running side by side with your wordpress blog. Such that you existing blog resides at http://blog.yourdomain.com and your rails app at http://yourdomain.com. If you are using apache / passenger this is pretty straight forward with "[virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)". You end up with one virtual host for your rails app and another for your wordpress blog. Another option could be to try using a single virtual host but using an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) to redirect to your wordpress blog.

Comment: There is also an experimental Rack middleware: https://github.com/eric1234/rack-legacy But the developer states that it is early alpha, so you probably shouldn't use it in production.

Comment: Alpha status... *Definitely* shouldn't use it in production

Comment: `rack-legacy` shouldn't even be necessary, because your shouldn't run your rack application pure. It's better to have something like apache or nginx in front of you rack/rails-application. And these servers can both handle the "legacy" directly, without the need of another rack applcition

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which http server you use. So I know how it can be done for apache and nginx:

[The easiest way](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) is to use [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) formerly known as mod_rails. This is a module/plugin for apache or nginx which can run rack applications, and rails is a rack application.

You can simply install it with

```
[sudo] gem install passenger
```

What to do after this depends on you webserver:

- [apache](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html):

  ```
  [sudo] passenger-install-apache2-module
  ```
- [nginx](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html)

  ```
  [sudo] passenger-install-nginx-module
  ```

Both of these commands provide a pretty good discription of what to do. If you're using nginx it's possible you need to recompile the webserver, but in the case of nginx it's quite fast.